# Confusion in order of Destructor call in Python

Tags: python, destructor

I was going through this website http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python, I wrote the exactly similar code.
But in my code, the `destructor` is getting called once the object goes out of scope. But the code mentioned in the link above, the `destructor` gets called after the end of the code. How?

Here are codes;

Code from the link

```
class FooType(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        print self.id, 'born'

    def __del__(self):
        print self.id, 'died'

def make_foo():
    print 'Making...'
    ft = FooType(1)
    print 'Returning...'
    return ft

print 'Calling...'
ft = make_foo()
print 'End...'
Output is :
Calling...
Making...
1 born
Returning...
End...
1 died <----- Destructor called
```

My Code:

```
abc = [1,2,3]
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "const"
    abc = [7,8,9]
    a = 4
    def __del__(self):
        print "Dest"
def hello():
    abc = [4,5]
    print abc
    my = myclass()
    print my.abc, my.a
    print "I am before Dest"
    return "Done"

ret = hello()
print ret
print abc
```

output:

```
[4, 5]
const
[7, 8, 9] 4
I am before Dest
Dest<---------- Destructor
Done
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Because the program doesn't end immediately when the last line you wrote gets executed, there's still some tidying up to do (e.g. your object being dereferenced and `__del__`eted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the object is returned by the function it is still in scope in the main program. In your example the object never leaves the function, so it goes out of scope when the function returns.